# The name 'clinics' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have no real idea what this means as I'm not so good with C# or Visual Studio. I am creating a basic console which will display data from a database.

this is the program.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assessment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirstQuery();
        }

        private static void FirstQuery()
        {
            using (var context = new AssessmentEntities())
            {
                var clinic = context.Clinics;
                Console.WriteLine("Query Result");
                foreach (var clinic in clinics)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}".clinic.clinic_id, clinic.clinci_name);
                }
                Console.Write("Press return to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other code you will need to look at so just let me know and I will paste it in. Thank you

The error code I get is ("The name 'clinics' does not exist in the current context)

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @Sam1 I get The name 'clinic' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: change `var clinic = context.Clinics;` to `var clinics = context.Clinics;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a typo, instead of

```
var clinic = context.Clinics;
```

there should be

```
var clinics = context.Clinics;
```

Comment: I feel like such a tool, this is what I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Change this from

```
foreach (var clinic in clinics)
{
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}".clinic.clinic_id, clinic.clinci_name);
}
```

To

```
foreach (var c in clinic)
{
          Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}".c.clinic_id, c.clinic_name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a typo (clinics instead of clinic)

The easiest change would be to alter the allocation to be clinics -

```
var clinics = context.Clinics;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var clinics = context.Clinics;
```

instead of

```
var clinic = context.Clinics;
```